# Laravel How to transfer specific shop id in foreach to controller

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, forms, foreach

I want to get the specific value of the shop id when the button is clicked. I have foreach display the shop name and its products. What I want to do is when the x button is clicked it will transfer the $shop->id to the controller, Once the value has been detected, it will be deleted in the table Carts.

I have something like this:

```
@foreach ($getShopName as $shop)
<form id="x-cart" action="{{ route('cartconfigurations') }}" method="post">
@csrf
 
    <input class="shop-radio" type="checkbox" name="shop-radio[]" value="{{ $shop->id }}" data-seller-id="{{ $shop->id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="shop-to-remove[]" value="{{ $shop->id }}">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">{{ $shop->shop_name }}</label>
 
 
 
   <button class="btn d-xxl-flex close delete-shop-button" type="button" data-shop-id="{{ $shop->id }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="deleteshop">                     
   </button>
```

I've spent hours trying everything because I have difficulty dealing with arrays. What I'm expecting is when the button is clicked it will transfer the specific $shop->id in controllers to be deleted.

Tried using dd(); but I always get [] when a checkbox is not selected which is not what I wanted.

Here is the code for the X button to remove the shop from the database:

`<button class="btn d-xxl-flex close delete-shop-button" type="button" data-shop-id="{{ $shop->id }}"> <input type="hidden" name="action" value="deleteshop">                      </button>`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I don't think you need a checkbox here at all as there is no need to specify an ID within a single iteration anyway.

You can specify a variable to be supplied to your route in Laravel, in this case i.e.

```
cartconfigurations/{id}
```

You can check the Laravel documentation on how to do that. Then simply have the form post to

```
"'cartconfigurations/' + $shop->id"
```

and use this id variable in the controller to specify a shop to delete.

The syntax above for adding variables to a link might not work verbatim in Blade though, since I only ever used it in Vue components, but hopefully you get the gist of it.

I would also suggest having multiple different routes for CRUD operations, rather than having them all together under one. It's not really a problem for simple apps, but it's not the best practice as it can get complicated rather quickly.

Comment: But the checkbox is required for another function for removing specific products from a shop. I just want to have the datas prepared in the x button to be transferred to the Controller. But I will try your method thank you!